# I can't call 'snapshot.documentChanges' in Firestore addSnapshotListener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't call `snapshot.documentChanges` in `addSnapshotListener`

It said `Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'documentChanges'`

Xcode 10.2, Swift 5, Firestore 5.10.0 and more information about other libraries are down below

```
    fileprivate func setupSnapshotListener() {
        let coupleId = "B9C950640E1B3740E98ACB93E669C65766F6670DD1609BA91FF41052BA48C6F3"

        let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("couples").document(coupleId).collection("vibrations").document("vibrationStatus")

        ref.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                if (diff.type == .added) {
                    print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
                }
                if (diff.type == .modified) {
                    print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
                }
                if (diff.type == .removed) {
                    print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Podfile

```
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore’,’~>5.10.0’
  pod 'Firebase/Auth’,’~>5.10.0’
  pod 'Firebase/Storage’,’~>5.10.0’
  pod 'Firebase/Core’
  pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '~> 5.2.0'
  pod 'JGProgressHUD','~>2.0.3'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
```

I expected to use `addListener` like Google Firebase Document said, but I can't call `documentChanges`!!

Comment: You are referencing to a document in stead of performing a query (like they do in the firestore example on their website). Thats why you get **Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'documentChanges'**

Comment: @AchidFarooq I can't understand exactly what you mean. What's an example of 
a query?

Comment: No problem, an query is like this -> Firestore.firestore().collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA") What you have is like this -> Firestore.firestore().collection("couples").document(coupleId).collection("vibrations").document("vibrationStatus")

You are specifically looking for a document in stead of perfoming a query. There is a difference in firestore in a Query() of in a DocumentReference()

Comment: @AchidFarooq Thank you so much!!! It works!! thx bro

Comment: no problem, good luck!